# mysql DATE_FORMAT using select *

Tags: mysql, date-format

generally when i make a small select I would do something like this

```
SELECT id,DATE_FORMAT(updated,'%M %e, %Y %l:%i %p'),title from tablename;
```

and that would give me a date format that I like.

Now I have an instance where I have a select where I don't want to specify every column because I know I want them all. However I also need to format dates the way i did in the previous example.

is there a way to format say just the updated column and all other feilds and still keep there order ?

i tried this

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(updated,'%M %e, %Y %l:%i %p') as updated from tablename
```

but that doesn't seem to be doing anyhting

Comment: Why are you trying to specify output format in SQL? That should be a job for the presentation tier.

Comment: because its much easier in my case to do it here

Comment: It will almost always be easier and more maintainable to do formatting in the presentation tier (or reporting engine) than in SQL. The SQL language, regardless of db product, is generally not geared towards presentation tasks. It is geared to return data.

Answer (score -1):

I did not tested but you could try with this

```
SELECT t.*,DATE_FORMAT(updated,'%M %e, %Y %l:%i %p')
as updated from tablename as t;
```